# Mongodb native validation for embedded documents

Tags: mongodb, validation, database-schema

I'm trying to come up with a Mongodb's native validation rule that will validate a document (having an embedded document) such that either the embedded document is not present at all OR if present, it has one or more fields mandatorily present.

I have got an example below. A JSON document has an embedded document `user`. This `user` may not exist or when it exists it needs to have a field `name` mandatorily present.

```
"validator" : {
        "$or" : [
            {
                "user" : {
                    "$exists" : "false",
                    "$type" : "null"
                }
            },
            {
                "user.name" : {
                    "$type" : "string",
                    "$exists" : "true"
                }
            }
            ]
}
```

And when I try to insert an empty JSON document to my collection `testschema` like `db.testschema.insert({})`, I get the standard error below which doesn't tell what is wrong and/or why. This should be possible because my document can either contain an embedded document `user` with a field `name` or not contain the embedded document at all.

```
WriteResult({
    "nInserted" : 0,
    "writeError" : {
        "code" : 121,
        "errmsg" : "Document failed validation"
    }
})
```

Are the operators used inside the validator looking correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing `null`, `true` and `false` should not be passed as strings, `false` passed as the string will evaluate to `true` only.

Solution No need of "$type" : null validator, just "$exists" : false is enough for your case, The following validation will work for you

```
"validator" : {
        "$or" : [
            {
                "user" : {
                    "$exists" : false,
                }
            },
            {
                "user.name" : {
                    "$type" : "string",
                    "$exists" : true
                }
            }
            ]
}
```

Comment: wow, that's so dumb of me! I remember how I got the double quotes - when you run the `db.getCollectionInfos({name:'testschema'})[0].options.validator` command to see what validation rules are set already, the Mongo shell wraps these boolean values in double quotes! Thanks for this nice tip! Much appreciated.

Comment: Happy to help!!